# firebase data change method in android studio

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

how email's value change from "app-user/users"?

Firebase state :
[image]

this isn't web language, i use javacode and xml of androidstudio.

i'm tryed under code.

```
databaseReference.child(app-user).child(user).orderByChild("email").equalTo("user4~~")
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Please make sure the code you include is what you actually tried, as it now seems unlikely that the code even compiles.

Comment: Because I do not know how to find and change the value.

Comment: I do not know how to put the code from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all users whose email address starts with `user4`:

```
DatabaseReference usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("app-users/users");
Query usersQuery = usersRef.orderByChild("email").startAt("user4").endAt("user4\uF7FF");

usersQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            System.out.println(userSnapshot.getKey()+": "+userSnapshot.getChild("displayName").getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

To understand the `usersRef.orderByChild("email").startAt("user4").endAt("user4\uF7FF")` query, read it as:

- Take all child nodes of `usersRef` and order them by their `email` property.
- Then find the first child node that starts with `user4`.
- Then return each child node, until you find a child that starts with `.endAt("user4\uF7FF")` (or further).

In this the `\uF7FF` is no magic code, but just the last known Unicode character. So by combining `.startAt("user4").endAt("user4\uF7FF")`, you're building a `startsWith` operator.

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you first.
In my opinion, it seems to read and sort data from DB.
I want a way to change this particular value if the email has the same specific value in the email.
The specific value here is user4@gmail.com.

Comment: In that case your query is `.equalTo("user4@gmail.com")` instead of `.startAt("user4").endAt("user4\uF7FF")`.

Comment: I got your email information with your help. But what I want is to change the value of email.
ex ) user4@gmail.com -> polish@gmail.com

Comment: I want to change only the value of an email without changing other information.